# left cosets of $\langle18\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

What are all the left cosets of $\langle18\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$.

According to Lagrange Theorem, if $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $[G:H]=\frac{|G|}{|H|}$ So $|G|=26$ and $|H|=13$ right? Meaning $[G:H]=2$. So would the 2 distinct left cosest just be,

$\{0,18,10,2,20,12,4,22,14,6,24,16,8\}$

$\{1, 19, 11, 3, 21, 13, 5, 23, 15, 7, 25, 17, 9\}$

by taking $0 + \langle18\rangle$ and $1+\langle18\rangle$.

Comment: Of course, since $\gcd(18,26)=2$, in $\left(\mathbb{Z}/26\mathbb{Z},+\right)$ we have $\langle 18\rangle = \langle 2\rangle$ and everything should be pretty clear. It is an abelian group so you can remove "*left*" from "*left cosets*".

Comment: Yes. You seem to have everything.